# Autoplay Youtube video - iframe

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, embed, autoplay

As you could make a Youtube video it will automatically run ?

I used autoplay = 1 and does not work

The video is for Android app

The code from the video is:

```
    <div class="demo-wrapper" data-role="page" id="tutoPage" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <div class="header" data-role="header">
        <span class="title">Tutorial</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-role="content">
        <iframe id="bgvid"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*****?rel=0&autoplay=1" ></iframe>
        <div id="tutorial" >
            <a id='tuto' href='#initPage' >continuar</a>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `;` before `autoplay=1` with `&`.

**EDIT:** autoplay doesn't work on webviews. You have to use [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to achieve that.

Comment: remove the `&amp` too.

Comment: The link you have is now fine. The problem is not with the link, I've tested it. Can you show us more info please?

Comment: I've realized now that autoplay on webview's on android doesn't work anymore. You have to use [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to achieve that

Comment: @PedroVB you have step by step instructions on the link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the url like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/*******?rel=0&autoplay=1
```

Comment: what is the difference??

Comment: You edited the question after I posted answer. Before, it was `https://www.youtube.com/embed/*******?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1`